# jquery moving element at the end of the list makes container disapper, seems like prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a very simple rotating banners list.

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/a9dAm/

```
if ($("#ads").length > 0) {
    var count_banners = $("#ads a").length;
    var delay_time = 1000;
    var i = 1;

    while (count_banners >= i) {
        $("#ads a:nth-child("+ i +")").delay(delay_time * i).show(1, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut("slow").prepend($("#ads"));
        });
        i++;
    }
}
```

Prepend breaks everything and #ads disappears all together, what is going on? or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `.prependTo()`, not `.prepend()`.

```
        $(this).fadeOut("slow").prependTo($("#ads"));
```

or just

```
        $(this).fadeOut("slow").prependTo("#ads");
```

The `.prepend()` function prepends its argument to the element from which you call it.

Answer (score 1):

It's disappearing because you were using `.prepend` rather than `.prependTo`. Basically, you were moving ads instead of the single ad.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klatzkaj/a9dAm/1/

This is the relevant line: `$(this).fadeOut("slow").prependTo($("#ads"));`